# Postgres conditional unique constraint without select

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following table:

Cars: id, name, status

I want to enforce a conditional constraint on the car's name as soon as we have a record for that name with status `SOLD`.

Example:

```
1, 'BMW', 'NEW'
2, 'BMW', 'NEW'
3, 'BMW', 'SOLD'
4, 'BMW', 'NEW'
```

The first 3 records should be inserted fine. But the 4th record should not be inserted because we now have a BMW with status `SOLD`.

This is what I've tried:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cars_sold ON cars (name) WHERE (status = 'SOLD');
```

This doesn't work as I might have hoped. This only ensures that we can't have 2 `BMW` that is `SOLD`

NOTE: I can accomplish this with a `INSERT SELECT`, but this table is going to grow very large so I would want the performance of a unique constraint enforcement. I also seen I can do this with `CONSTRAINT CHECK`, but I believe it basically does a `SELECT` under the hood.

Is there anyway to accomplish this without the performance hit of a `SELECT` on a large table? Conceptually it seems like I will always have to do a `SELECT`

Comment: I think you have to use a trigger for this.  The data structure is quite curious.  Why not just do an update?

Comment: @GordonLinoff will the trigger have to run the select under the hood? i'm really trying to avoid the performance hit of the select, otherwise I would just do an insert select

Comment: The criteria involves information that's not available from the current record.  Maybe use an external table to track the status.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this with a constraint because a constraint always checks the *current state* of the database and does not consider the order in which modifications were applied.

I think that you best solve the problem with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that runs a `SELECT` statement for a car with the same name and the status `SOLD`. The unique partial index that you created in your question should make such a `SELECT` blazingly fast, no matter how big the table is.

Comment: I believe my constraint doesn't need to know the order which modifications were applied. It only needs the current state of the database. Going back to my example, when number 4 is applied, it doesn't care which order 1,2,3 were applied, it just cares that #3 has a `BMW` with state `SOLD`.

Comment: Also, how will the partial index help me? Is it because the index tree is much smaller now since it only contains values where the status is `SOLD`?

Comment: If you assume that increasing `id` reflects the time of the modification, you are right (but don't count on that if there is high concurrency). Still I cannot think of a constraint that would reflect that. The partial index will be fast because it is unique - it hits the matching leaf entry quick and does not have to scan.